# In menus for "...", should one use ellipsis sign or just three dots?

Tags: user-interface, menu

[Microsoft's reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511502.aspx#ellipses) doesn't say anything, but it seems that currentle everyone uses three dots (...) and not the unicode sign (…).

Is it OK, or maybe there are some guidelines I'm not aware of that recommend using the unicode sign?

Comment: Microsoft's document on **Menus** has moved [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742392.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's safer to use three dots, because some fonts/systems might not interpret correctly the '...' single character.

Comment: Still, remember that the ellipses do take less space so you could use them if you know exactly that your default fonts from the target systems do support them.